# Cохранение css файл другом папке после его компиляции

Tags: phpstorm, css, less

Как после компиляции less файла сохранить другом папке css файл?

Сохраняет так

```
D:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\test\wp-content\plugins\x\css\less\style.css
```

Нужно сохранить так

```
D:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\test\wp-content\plugins\x\css\style.css
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шторм компилирует sass/less c помощью т.н. file watchers - обработчиков, которые решают куда, чем и куда комплиировать. Необходимо открыть в проекте обработчик для этого файла, и поиграться с `insert macro` в поле `output paths`, я так понимаю, достаточно будет `$FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` или даже `../$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`